# mongoDB mongoimport error .. getting file doesn't exist error

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I am a newbie in Mongodb. when i am trying to mongoimport i am getting the below error.

I have the file placed in c:\mongo\data\db\mongo.csv ... can anyone pls help me.

```
C:\mongodb\bin>mongoimport.exe -d test -c foo --file c:\mongo\data\db\mongo.csv --type csv

connected to: 127.0.0.1
file doesn't exist: c:\mongo\data\db\mongo.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

either you should give path like as you are in **C** directive only

```
C:\mongodb\bin>mongoimport.exe -d test -c foo --file /mongo/data/db/mongo.csv --type csv
```

or you can give path in a qoute (**" "**) as mentioned by Gianpj

```
C:\mongodb\bin>mongoimport.exe -d test -c foo --file "c:\mongo\data\db\mongo.csv" --type csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the file does exist? There are no spaces in the file path?
Try with double quotes:

```
--file "c:\mongo\data\db\mongo.csv"
```

Lastly where did got that .csv file? from `mongoexport --csv` ?